# Giving FFmpeg access to my app's data directory?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm working with one of the many Android FFmpeg libraries on GitHub, which each involve an NDK wrapper around a C binary. I'm trying to give other apps access to the video file I have edited with FFmpeg (and saved in External Storage), but at least on Android 6.0, the new permissions system prevents them from being able to access the shared file unless they themselves have the External Storage permission granted. The solution here would be to use content providers to open up a directory for other apps to access. However...

My FFmpeg binary is contained within the app's data directory, but it fails when I try to access or modify a video file saved there. As mentioned above, it has no problem accessing external storage.

Is there a way to give FFmpeg access to my app's data directory, giving it read and write permissions? Would naming the library with the same package name do the trick?

Any ideas? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Did you try to run this ffmpeg binary from `adb shell`?

Comment: At any rate, to put the video files onto your app data directory isn't a good idea, the size of this partition is usually very limited.